# How can I intersect multiple query with EntityFramework for a search?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, search, entity-framework-4

When people do a search of my website, I don't want to just search the value (q), I want to search each word with the space as separator. I've made up most of the code but there are parts that I don't know how to do.

Can you check the "todo" in the code below and suggest me a way to do it? Or maybe a total different approach. By the way, I want to keep the SQL code part if it's possible because it's more natural to me but all the TODO could be done in LINQ.

Thanks

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Search(string q)
        {
            ViewBag.q = q;

            String[] strQueries = q.Split(' ');

            //TODO: Create an array of type var???

            foreach (string str in strQueries)
            {
                var recipesTemp = db.Recipes.SqlQuery(
                String.Format(
                "SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%' " +
                "UNION ALL " +
                "SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE IDRecipe IN ( " +
                "    SELECT IDRecipe FROM Subtitle WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%') " +
                "UNION ALL  " +
                "SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE IDRecipe IN ( " +
                "    SELECT IDRecipe FROM RecipeTag " +
                "        INNER JOIN Tag ON Tag.IDTag = RecipeTag.IDTag  " +
                "    WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%') " +
                "UNION ALL   " +
                "SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE IDRecipe IN ( " +
                "    SELECT IDRecipe FROM Subtitle " +
                "        INNER JOIN Ingredient ON Ingredient.IDSubtitle = Subtitle.IDSubtitle  " +
                "    WHERE QuantityAndName LIKE '%{0}%')", str)).Distinct().OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList();

                //TODO: Add recipesTemp to the array of var
            }

            var recipes = //TODO: INTERSECT the results from all the recipesTemp in the array of type var

            return View("Search", recipes);
        }
```

Comment: If there's a "recipe" here, it's for a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Beside the security concern, do you have an idea on how to do this? And what would you suggest to avoid SQL Injection attack in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will do the trick:

```
        var selectedRecipies = new List<IEnumerable<Recipy>>();

        foreach(...)
        {
            ...
            selectedRecipies.Add(recipesTemp);
        }

        var recipies = selectedRecipies.Aggregate((a, i) => a.Intersect(i));
```

Besides, in you place, I would also take comment of @KirkWoll into account and use FullTextSearch instead of LIKEs.

Comment: I know what is FullTextSearch (Lucene for example) but I always think that it was to search in big amount of text. In my case, I'm only searching in 4 tables of very small size (varchar of lenght 50). Does FullTextSearch be a good match for this?

Comment: Right, there is a 'built-in' FullTextSearch feature in MSSQL, so you don't have to install Lucene. Nevertheless, it will show itself on big amount of text or on synonims' search, so you may forget about it for the time it will actually become an issue for you.

Comment: For you information, I use your technique and I will translate the part in SQL in my query to linq to avoid sql injection! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

For each `str` in `strQueries` you're creating a distinct formated SQL queries sorted by name and stored in `List<T>` where `T` is a `Recipe` (?). Try something like that:

```
var allRecipes = strQueries.Select(str => db.Recipes.SqlQuery(
    String.Format(
        "SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%' " +
        "UNION ALL " +
        "SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE IDRecipe IN ( " +
        "    SELECT IDRecipe FROM Subtitle WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%') " +
        "UNION ALL  " +
        "SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE IDRecipe IN ( " +
        "    SELECT IDRecipe FROM RecipeTag " +
        "        INNER JOIN Tag ON Tag.IDTag = RecipeTag.IDTag  " +
        "    WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%') " +
        "UNION ALL   " +
        "SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE IDRecipe IN ( " +
        "    SELECT IDRecipe FROM Subtitle " +
        "        INNER JOIN Ingredient ON Ingredient.IDSubtitle = Subtitle.IDSubtitle  " +
        "    WHERE QuantityAndName LIKE '%{0}%')", str)).Distinct().OrderBy(recipe => recipe.Name))
    .SelectMany(recipe => recipe);
```

After that `allRecipes` should by of type `IEnumerable<Recipe>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach which will result in a single SQL statement:

```
var names = q.Split(' ');

if(names.Any())
{
    var firstName = names[0];

    var query = context.Recipes.Where (q => q.Name.Contains(firstName));
    // other unions ...
    // query = query.Union( context.Recipes.Where (...
    foreach (var name in names.Skip(1))
    {
        query = query.Union(context.Recipes.Where (q => q.Name.Contains(name)));
        // other unions ...
        // query = query.Union( context.Recipes.Where (...
    }

    // query evaluated now
    var recipes = query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think using your approach, the first name will be search only in the recipe name but the other will be search in all the other places (tags, ingredient, etc). I want all the names from the split to be searched in the 4 places. But I understand the idea behind your answer and will try to implement it tonight